# UITableView methods are called before ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, viewdidload

I'm trying to create a simple weather app which gets data from OpenweatherMap using JSON and print them out in a UITableView. However, when I executed this code below and set a breakpoint at `numberOfRowsInSection` method, it returns 0 row. Somehow the `viewDidLoad` method was called after the `numberOfRowsInSection` method, that's why the threeHoursForecast array is empty. Can anyone help me on this please?

```
static NSString * const BaseURLString = @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Houston";

@interface HPViewController ()

@end

@implementation HPViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.threeHoursForecast = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:nil
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

              NSArray *data = [responseObject objectForKey:@"list"];

              for (NSDictionary *forecastPerThreeHours in data)
                  [self.threeHoursForecast addObject:[[forecastPerThreeHours valueForKey:@"main"] valueForKey:@"temp"]];
          }

          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
          }];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.threeHoursForecast count];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reload data after the completion handler is called, which will solve the problem.

```
[manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:nil
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

              NSArray *data = [responseObject objectForKey:@"list"];

              for (NSDictionary *forecastPerThreeHours in data)
                  [self.threeHoursForecast addObject:[[forecastPerThreeHours valueForKey:@"main"] valueForKey:@"temp"]];

              //Add this line 
              [self.TableView reloadData];
          }

          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
          }];
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I did try reloading data before but I put it outside the success block of request so it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

The post method is async. You need to add `[self.tableView reloadData];` in succes block of request.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I did try reloading data before but I put it outside the success block of request so it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`manager POST:` is asynchronous call, so you need to reload data after fetching JSON.

```
 [manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:nil
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                  NSArray *data = [responseObject objectForKey:@"list"];

                  for (NSDictionary *forecastPerThreeHours in data)
                      [self.threeHoursForecast addObject:[[forecastPerThreeHours valueForKey:@"main"] valueForKey:@"temp"]];

                  // [NOTE]
                  [self.tableView reloadData];
              }

              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {    
                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
              }];
```